# T-SQL Self Join Table with External Table Grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, rollup

The desired result will be a grouping of the first set based on the second. There is a group of people that should be matched to other people, separated by "rooms" so each room is used uniformly. So with 5 persons and 7 rooms, there are 20 combinations so each room will be used no more than 3 times (tangent: each room is used sequentially so there is no danger of a person being in more than one place at a time). There are 3 pairs per grouping, but as additional groups rows are added, the number of pairs-per-group should diminish; if additional groups rows are deleted, then number of pairs-per-group should increase. If I wasn't thinking in Sets, it feels like a RBAR operation because I only want each room to be used as the number of people combinations divided by the number of groups - 20 combinations / 7 groups = 3 combinations per group, but 20 combinations / 5 groups = 4 combinations per group.

The result set looks like this currently:

```js
person1    person2
person1    person3
person1    person4
person1    person5
person2    person1
person2    person3
person2    person4
person2    person5
person3    person1
person3    person2
person3    person4
person3    person5
person4    person1
person4    person2
person4    person3
person4    person5
person5    person1
person5    person2
person5    person3
person5    person4
```

But I am trying to figure out how to make it look like this:

```js
01-01    person1    person2
01-01    person1    person3
01-01    person1    person4
01-02    person1    person5
01-02    person2    person1
01-02    person2    person3
01-03    person2    person4
01-03    person2    person5
01-03    person3    person1
01-04    person3    person2
01-04    person3    person4
01-04    person3    person5
01-05    person4    person1
01-05    person4    person2
01-05    person4    person3
01-06    person4    person5
01-06    person5    person1
01-06    person5    person2
01-07    person5    person3
01-07    person5    person4
```

Here is the T-SQL I have so far:

```
If Object_Id('TempDb..#namez') Is Not Null 
     Drop Table #namez

Create Table #namez
(
     namezId Int Not Null Primary Key,
     membername VarChar(48)
)

Insert Into #namez
Values (10 ,'person1'), (11 , 'person2'),
       (12 , 'person3'), (13 , 'person4'),
       (14 , 'person5')

If Object_Id('TempDb..#groups') Is Not Null 
     Drop Table #groups

Create Table #groups
(
    groupsId Int Not Null Primary Key,
    GroupCode Char(5)
)

Insert Into #groups
Values (10, '01-01'), (11, '01-02'), (12, '01-03'),
       (13, '01-04'), (14, '01-05'), (15, '01-06'), (16, '01-07')


Select 
    TeamOne.membername, TeamTwo.membername 
From    
    #namez TeamOne 
Full Outer Join 
    #namez TeamTwo On TeamOne.membername != TeamTwo.membername
order by 
    teamone.membername, teamtwo.membername
```

Thanks!

Comment: would it always be 3 pairs per group?

Comment: Just reread it, uniformly across the groups, so not always 3...

Comment: are the groups in your table, the GroupID, always sequential?  You can get a grouping of your teams.  I'm trying to then think through how we'd related that back to your group table.  If they are sequential, get the min and then some math to do the join...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tweaks to what you had.

We use row_number() to get a grouping of the teams based on how we need to split them up.  Then use that, plus the min() GroupId to join back to the groups table.

This assumes GroupId in the groups table is sequential and should account for more or less teams and more or less groups.

Give this a try:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#namez') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [#namez];

CREATE TABLE [#namez]
    (
        [namezId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      , [membername] VARCHAR(48)
    );

INSERT INTO [#namez]
VALUES ( 10, 'person1' )
     , ( 11, 'person2' )
     , ( 12, 'person3' )
     , ( 13, 'person4' )
     , ( 14, 'person5' );

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#groups') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [#groups];

CREATE TABLE [#groups]
    (
        [groupsId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      , [GroupCode] CHAR(5)
    );

INSERT INTO [#groups]
VALUES ( 10, '01-01' )
     , ( 11, '01-02' )
     , ( 12, '01-03' )
     , ( 13, '01-04' )
     , ( 14, '01-05' )
     , ( 15, '01-06' )
     , ( 16, '01-07' );


DECLARE @GroupComboCount INT
      , @GroupCount DECIMAL(12, 2)
      , @TeamCount DECIMAL(12, 2)
      , @MinGroupId INT;

--What is our group count
SET @GroupCount = (
                      SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM   [#groups]
                  );
--What is our team count
SET @TeamCount = (
                     SELECT          COUNT(*)
                     FROM            [#namez] [TeamOne]
                     FULL OUTER JOIN [#namez] [TeamTwo]
                         ON [TeamOne].[membername] != [TeamTwo].[membername]
                 );
--How should I uniformly split the teams 
SET @GroupComboCount = ROUND(@TeamCount / @GroupCount, 0);

--What is the min group so I can build my relationship back to groups.
SET @MinGroupId = (
                      SELECT MIN([groupsId])
                      FROM   [#groups]
                  );

SELECT   grp.*, [TeamGroups].*
FROM     (
             SELECT          ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [TeamOne].[membername]
                                                          , [TeamTwo].[membername]
                                                 ) + ( @GroupComboCount - 1 )
                             ) / @GroupComboCount AS [TeamGrouping] --This does my group based on the @GroupComboCount
                           , [TeamOne].[membername] AS [Member1]
                           , [TeamTwo].[membername] AS [Member2]
             FROM            [#namez] [TeamOne]
             FULL OUTER JOIN [#namez] [TeamTwo]
                 ON [TeamOne].[membername] != [TeamTwo].[membername]
         ) AS [TeamGroups]
INNER JOIN [#groups] grp ON grp.[groupsId] = @MinGroupId+[TeamGroups].[TeamGrouping]-1 --Here we then relate that back to my groups.
ORDER BY [TeamGroups].[Member1]
       , [TeamGroups].[Member2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`

[**DB FIDDLE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7412561a1918c8faefee2cf009951e47)

```
Select     TeamOne.membername , TeamTwo.membername 
From       #namez TeamOne 
cross join #namez TeamTwo
where      TeamOne.membername != TeamTwo.membername 
order by   teamone.membername,teamtwo.membername
```

Comment: How do I get the additional column #groups.groupscode to show in the final result?

Comment: Add it to the select list @Snowy after you join the table. I’ll edit the answer

Comment: I added groupscode and the row count exploded to 80 total, with repeats for each group. What I want is the row count to stay at 20 total with grouping by the groupcode so there are ~3 name pairs per group. Should there be a GROUP BY or subquery? Thanks.

Comment: Like so https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=41f0bdb9eef506f81a7df8a1b6b99e3d

Comment: The issue is that there are 7 rows in the #groups table, all of the groups (rooms) are not being used in the last query. If more room rows are added, there should be less pairings per room. Thanks.

Comment: I’m unsure what you mean unfortunately. Sorry